# Questions on Chomsky's "Syntactic structures" #1

Tags: syntax, chomsky

This would be my first series of questions on this book (Second ed).
Chomsky warns that several answers to the question "On what basis do we actually go about separating grammatical and ungrammatical sentences?" that immediately suggest, could not be true.

1- Please clarify this first:

http://cubeupload.com/im/na0wMq.jpg

2- Supposing the sentences (1) Colorless green ideas sleep furiously. and (2) Furiously sleep ideas green colorless. , clarify this part for me:

http://cubeupload.com/im/1uMUlC.png

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to linguistics beta, Amir, but this is really not a good place to ask about these issues. This book is 60 years old and is basically not read by anybody any more; it's like the manual for a toaster that hasn't been manufactured for two generations. There's very little value in reading it, if you're interested in syntax or linguistics. If you're interested in Chomsky's thought, that's a different matter; but not for the linguistic concepts.

Comment: Thanks but my aim is the Chomsky itself not modern linguistics.

Comment: Amir, you may want to point out as clearly as possible what your understanding of the relevant sections is and what specifically you don't understand. I could probably write a whole page on these sections and still miss what you want to talk about.

Comment: I agree with @robert - there's nothing wrong with asking about something in *syntactic structures*, but if you could indicate what you thought about these passages, and what particular things you don't understand, you'll probably get a better answer.

Comment: Your links are dead. In any case, avoid using links only to make a point because as you can see, they can stop working, thus rendering the whole post pointless. Indicating the title of the text and relevant chapters should be enough. Maybe linking to Google Books would be the best option, but still, make sure your question can stand even if the links die.